# MongoDB $in, $all with regular expressions

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

i'm working with mongodb and doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle i'm trying to build a query like this

```
$matches = array("/^abc/", "/^dbc/);

$this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->field('field_name')->in($matches)
    ->getQuery();
```

is use `$all` and `$in` conditional operators with regular expressions. it's posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but while I'm no PHP expert, it looks like `$matches` is an array of strings, not regular expressions.  You'd need to do something like this instead:

```
$matches = array(new MongoRegex("/^abc/"), new MongoRegex("/^dbc/"));
```

In the shell you'd do:

```
db.collection.find({field_name: {$in: [/^abc/, /^dbc/]}})
```